# Install Network-manager-applet (tray-icon) on Arch Linux GNOME 3.20

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

I am using Arch Linux with GNOME 3.20. I am trying to get a network manager applet (tray-icon) using which I could easily connect to WiFi networks.

I installed `networkmanager` and `network-manager-applet` but I am not getting any tray icon.

[image]

---

<sup>As I found that this is a commen problem and has less resources to look for a step-by-step solution, I thought it would be helpful for new users if I share how I solved this problem.</sup>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Initial Requirements

**Hosts**

Check the configuration of your `/etc/hosts file`, a valid configuration looks like this:

```
        #<ip-address>    <hostname.domain.org>    <hostname>
        127.0.0.1      localhost.localdomain    yourHostname
        ::1            localhost.localdomain    yourHostname
```

**Devices**

You can identify your networking-devices like this:

```
$ lspci | grep -i net
```

If your device is not listed, it is maybe an usb-device, so try this command:

```
$ lsusb
```

With the following command you can check the current state of all your network-devices:

```
$ ip link
```

---

### Installation of Required tools

Install the wpa_supplicant tools

```
$ sudo pacman -S wpa_supplicant
```

Install the wireless tools

```
$ sudo pacman -S wireless_tools
```

Install the networkmanager

```
$ sudo pacman -S networkmanager
```

Install the network-manager-applet aka nm-applet

```
$ sudo pacman -S network-manager-applet
```

Install gnome-keyring

```
$ sudo pacman -S gnome-keyring
```

---

### Configuration

Make the networkmanager start on boot:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```

**Disable dhcpcd**

Since networkmanager wants to be the one who handles the dhcpcd related stuff, you have to disable and stop dhcpcd:

```
 $ sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
 $ sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd@.service
 $ sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd.service
 $ sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd@.service
```

Enable wpa_supplicant, if you want to use your wireless connection:

```
 $ sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service
```

Add your user to the network group:

```
 $ gpasswd -a <USERNAME> network
```

**Turn off network interface controllers:**

Turn off your network interface controllers, in my case eth0 and wlan0:

```
 $ ip link set down eth0
 $ ip link set down wlan0
```

Now start wpa_supplicant:

```
 $ sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service
```

Now Start the networkmanager:

```
 $ sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Now you should See the tray-icon on the top bar

[image]

If you get an error about unreachable D-Bus, just ignore it.
If the networkmanager is not running and network-manager-applet does not show up in your upper GNOME3 panel, try this:

```
$ sudo Networkmanager
$ nm-applet
```

---

Comment: FYI this also worked for getting plasma-nm to work with KDE. THANK YOU.

Comment: works for XFCE too!!