# Arch linux: DHCPD fails on start: ipv6_addaddr1: No such device

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, wifi, dhcp, iwd

when I start my arch linux install on my thinkpad x390, I can not connect to the internet. It is because dhcdpd service failed. This is systemd log:

```
john@arch-thinkpad ~> sudo systemctl status dhcpcd@wlan0.service
× dhcpcd@wlan0.service - dhcpcd on wlan0
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-10-06 08:23:52 CEST; 3min 31s ago
    Process: 524 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd -q -w wlan0 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 35ms

říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad dhcpcd[531]: wlan0: carrier acquired
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad dhcpcd[531]: wlan0: IAID 54:b2:f8:91
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad dhcpcd[531]: wlan0: adding address fe80::a212:1e5d:56d8:6d6f
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad dhcpcd[531]: ipv6_addaddr1: No such device
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad dhcpcd[531]: wlan0: carrier lost
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad dhcpcd[524]: ipv6_addaddr1: No such device
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad dhcpcd[531]: wlan0: removing interface
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: dhcpcd@wlan0.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: dhcpcd@wlan0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
říj 06 08:23:52 arch-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopped dhcpcd on wlan0.
```

in `dmesg -w` is this:

```
[    2.387933] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlmvm doesn't allow to disable HW crypto, check swcrypto module parameter
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` is this:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1
```

This is output of `ip monitor link` if I let it run for few hours:

```
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 5: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether b2:ad:b0:ba:c5:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 7: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether b2:ad:b0:ba:c5:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 8: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether b2:ad:b0:ba:c5:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
Deleted 9: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether b2:ad:b0:ba:c5:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
q6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 10: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether b2:ad:b0:ba:c5:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: wwp0s20f0u7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether ea:dd:ce:51:3f:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
    link/ether
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:52:c8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When I run `sudo systemctl restart iwd.service && sudo dhcpcd wlan0` it starts working again.

What can cause this problem and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You could keep a `ip monitor link` running on a separate shell to see if `wlan0` interface actually disappears (or get renamed or...). Then `dmesg` (or `dmesg -w`) to check for kernel messages could also help.

Comment: @A.B I added information base on your comment. Do you have any suggestions how to deal with it ?

Comment: I don't know more beside the two suggestions I wrote. I rather doubt the message about disabling hw crypto is related to your problems.

Comment: @A.B I added `ip monitor link` output

Comment: It didn't expose any system anomaly (wlan0 never disappears). I don't have other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these commands, and the issue is gone for me.

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd@wlan0.service
sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd
reboot
```

If the above solution doesn't work. You can disable dhcpcd, and use network manager instead. Here is [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292196/481495) to instal network manager.